# How to make social media in one line?

Tags: html, plugins, facebook-social-plugins

I've try to make social media (google+,facebook,twitter)in one line but every social media has different line. [see this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/99955339@N06/10283780086/)

This code:

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <div style="float:left">
     <div class="g-plusone" data-size="small" data-href=""></div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left">
     <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;width=The+pixel+width+of+the+plugin&amp;height=21&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;send=false&amp;appId=196962990473575" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:The pixel width of the pluginpx; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left">
     <a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @twitter</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are your `<div> </div>` for Facebook and Twitter?

Comment: for facebook i use iframe and twitter like to